# I want to edit a Google Script so it will shuffle a specific row at a specific sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In this [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Yw4k_tCW7yhGHMzpjiRGZtypL2lyAhbb0PJAnAMij0/edit?usp=sharing) I have tried this code:

```
function shuffleRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  sheet.sort(function(a,b){return Math.floor(Math.random()*range)-Math.floor(Math.random()*range);
  });
  rg.setValues(sheet);
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Shuffle ZOO",
    functionName : "shuffleRows",
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Shuffle ZOO", entries);
};
```

It works fine when it comes to shuffle an entire sheet. However I need the script to shuffle a specific range, i.e I2:I8 in a specific sheet, i.e. Ark 5.

I think I have to replace with these line:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ark5");
  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:I8");
```

What do I need to edit?

Comment: *It works fine* Not possible. `sheet` is `undefined` inside `shuffleRows`. *I think I have to replace with these line* Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @TheMaster I did try indeed, but I kept failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function runOne(rs,re) {
  var rs=rs||2;//row start
  var re=re||8;//row end
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Ark5");
  var rg=sh.getRange(rs,1,re-rs+1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var iA=[];//The index array
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){iA.push(i)});
  var oA=[];
  iA.sort(function(a,b){return Math.floor(Math.random()*iA.length)-Math.floor(Math.random()*iA.length);});//apply sort to index array
  iA.forEach(function(e,i){oA.push(vA[iA[i]]);});//reposition rows based upon sorted index array
  sh.getRange(rs,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//post repositioned rows
}
```

Comment: Thank You. It works as intended, but on the way I ended up with the solution underneath while I needed to swap numbers with names in a certain row and only triggered by a button. You did answer the original question though :-)

Comment: Know sure what you mean by swapping numbers with names so when you ask the question please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it though I'm not sure it's the best solution.

```
function shuffleRows() {
//  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ark5");
//  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:I8");


  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ark5");
  var sh=ss;
  var rg=sh.getRange("I2:I8");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  vA.sort(function(a,b){return Math.floor(Math.random()*lr)-Math.floor(Math.random()*lr);
  });
  rg.setValues(vA);
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Bland alle dyrene",
    functionName : "shuffleRows",
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Bland alle dyrene", entries);
};
```

Comment: Your [sort algorithm is non deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/)

Comment: What does that mean? And can I optimize it then?

Comment: I mean - I can read, but I can't translate it into this specific matter.

Comment: Can't help you with that. If you have a specific/focussed issue implementing the algorithm, ask a new question with [mcve] after trying multiple times.